# What does "this" stand for here?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the code:

```
$(element, document).mousedown(function() {
        $(this).attr('id'); // get id of the element

});
```

how to rewrite the code without using `this`?

Comment: Why? What's wrong with it?

Comment: if `$(element, document)` in the question was changed to `$(selector, context)` then this is very relevant. you are asking a special case inside that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
$(element, document).mousedown(function(e) {
        $(e.target).attr('id'); // Get id of the element.
});
```

Answer (score 3):

> what is THIS stands for?

In this context, `this` points to the element that you are currently defining the `mousedown` property for.

I can't see a reason not to use it here. Can you elaborate on what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

A version without the `this` keyword:

```
var $element = $('#element');
$element.mousedown(function() {
    var id = $element.attr('id');
        // id is now 'element'
});
```

Comment: Actually wrong :) What if the #element selector matches more than 1 element? ;)

Comment: its an id how can it match more than 1!! :/

Comment: @zzzz Yeah, but if it's *not* an ID but a class, it could match multiple elements.

Comment: I know that #id should be unique.. but as with most things in web development you can't guarantee it. Also we are looking at a generic way to replace this here so a class selector or anything that returns multiple elements should be considered

Comment: @Tigraine: #element selects only one element always regardless of the incorrect HTML https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js#L1148

Comment: @Simeon: what you are doing is incorrect and I agree with @ tigraine on that but I was just pointing out that in this case it mgiht be right..

Comment: Can you please specify why my code is "incorrect"? It demonstrates how the OP's code snippet (using `this` on a single element) can be rewritten into not utilizing the `this` keyword. Which is exactly what he asked for. It is not an answer for multiple elements, which is not what is being asked. And I clarified this by using an ID instead of just a singularly named variable.

Answer (score 0):

In this case "this" is refering to the element that is being clicked. It's not required but you'll have to have code like this for every element:

```
$("#button").mousedown(function(){
 $("#button").attr("id");
})
```

It's much easier to leave it in

Comment: You were missing a close `"`.

Answer (score 0):

this in JavaScript stands for the execution context of a function. In this case you benefit from jQuery setting `this` to the element you bound things on. But with self-written functions you'll usually end up with this referring to the global object.

In case you ever enter a new function scope you usually have to preserve this because a new function has a new this.

For example

```
$('div').each(function(index, item) {
    var that = this;
    $(this).mousedown(function() {
        //this could be something different than before 
        //so we use the that reference
        $(that).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

"this" refers to the scope of the function. With regards to the function, This is the element being acted upon. In the case of you code, the action is mousedown, so the element being acted upon is this. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not going to get anything more efficient than use of `this`. Everything else will more or less require a second element lookup which, while not deathly expensive is nevertheless more costly than using the object in scope (`this`).

Strictly speaking, this is the most literal interpretation:

```
$(element, document).mousedown(function() {
        $(element, document).attr('id'); 
});
```

Now, this might be OK, but if your element is actually a selector which returns multiple values (like a class selector), you'll have problems. So, instead, you might want to consider:

```
$(element, document).each( function( ind, elem ) {
    elem.mousedown( function(){ elem.attr( 'id' ); } );
} );
```